# How can I check if elements in my array list is ending with character "_bp"

Tags: java, arraylist, string-matching

How can I check if elements in my ArrayList are ending with "_bp" and append that suffix when they don't.
It would be great if i don't have to convert my ArrayList into String.

I tried below code:

```
ArrayList<String> comparingList = new ArrayList<String>(); 

String search = "_bp";
for (String str : comparingList)
{
    if (str.trim().contains(search))
    {
        // Do Nothing
    }
    else
    {
        str.trim().concat("_bp");
        //Replace existing value with this concated value to array list
    }
}
```

But I am still not able to append "_bp" in the existing element, also dont want to convert my
comparingList into String.

A smaller code is preferable if possible.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Why not use`'String.endswith("_bp");` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
String a = "test";
System.out.println("1 " + a.concat("_bp"));
System.out.println("2 " + a);
a = a.concat("_bp");
System.out.println("3 " + a);
```

output:

1 test_bp

2 test

3 test_bp

code like this:

```
        ArrayList<String> comparingList = new ArrayList<String>(); 
        comparingList.add("test1_bp");
        comparingList.add("test2");
        String search = "_bp";
        for (int i = 0; i < comparingList.size(); i++) {
            String tmpStr = comparingList.get(i);
            if(tmpStr.contains(search)){
                //do nothing
            }else{
                comparingList.set(i, tmpStr+"_bp"); 
            }
        }
        System.out.println(comparingList);
```

Comment: String search = "_vw";
    int i = 0;
    for (String str : comparingList)
     {
      if (str.trim().contains(search))
       {

       } else
       {
        comparingList.set(i, str.trim().concat("_vw"));
       }
      i++;
     }

Comment: sorry replaced "_bp" by "_vw"

Answer (score 0):

This worked :)

```
String search = "_bp";
int i = 0;
for (String str : comparingList)
{
    if (str.trim().contains(search))
    {

    } 
    else
    {
       comparingList.set(i, str.trim().concat("_bp"));
    }
    i++;
}
```